# Impresión directa de PDF (Array de Bytes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Situación: Tengo una solución C# en la cual tengo que imprimir directamente un array de bytes de me devuelve un Web Service (es un PDF).
La idea es mandarlo directamente a impresora sin utilizar el Acrobat.
Hay posibilidad o tengo que utilizar si o si el Acrobat?
Gracias.

Comment: En principio y por defecto, una aplicación web no tiene acceso a la impresora del equipo de ninguna de las maneras, así que me temo que es el usuario el que debe mandar a imprimir.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo necesitas escribir los bytes en la página, con el tipo application/pdf y el explorador automáticamente iniciará la descarga

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=archivo.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
Response.End();
```